# 'dev' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, github, git-push

I am new to git and I saw some people use this blow command:

```
git push -f dev HEAD:master
```

and when I try it this is the error I see:

> 'dev' does not appear to be a git repository

how can I know what dev is? is there a command to show the URL of it?

Comment: `git remote -v` to list all remote repositories

Comment: Use `git remote -v`, and replace `dev` with the name of the remote you want to use for the `push` operation.  My guess is that `dev` isn't a repository, which is why you are getting an error.

Comment: Use `git remote show origin` to find the URL for a remote named `origin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dev` is not a `git` keyword. Using `git push dev` you assume that `dev` is a git remote known by your git repository.

By default you get only one remote named `origin`. A proper command will be `git push origin`

To list all remotes, use `git remote -v`